# Ajax POST not working properly, PHP counterpart works flawlessly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I need to develop a javascript mobile app that needs to POST an authentication token to a Microsoft website.

I found the most of the code online in javascript so I tried it, but it fails.

The javascript code gives back a "GET undefined/proxy/https://mysharepointonline.sharepoint.com/_forms/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0" message in the console.

I also found a **WORKING** PHP version of the code, that, to me, seems like it's doing the same thing, but the way the POST is built up, that's where some slight differences may be.

The Javascript code is here:

```
function getAuthCookies()
{
    $.support.cors = true; // enable cross-domain query

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: token,   //this translates to the $token variable in php
        crossDomain: true, // had no effect, see support.cors above
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",   //'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        url: loginUrl,   //this translates to the $url variable in php      
        // dataType: 'html', // default is OK: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html)
        success: function (data, textStatus, result) {
            //function to call when the POST was successfull.
            refreshDigestViaREST();
        },
        error: function (result, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            reportError(result, textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

The PHP looks like this :

```
function getAuthCookies($token, $host) {

    $url = $host . "/_forms/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$token);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    //curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); // For testing
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    // catch error
    if($result === false) {
        throw new Exception('Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch));
    } 
    //close connection
    curl_close($ch);        
    return getCookieValue($result);
}
```

Can somebody highlight the differences in these two posts? 
And can somebody build a javascript post just like the php one?

EDIT:

The javascript code makes two requests, one after the other. The first one is moved temporarily but it actually has the right data in the response. The second one, however, has an invalid URL.

[image]

Comment: You should show what the JavaScript `url` variable is.

Comment: `POST an authentication token to a Microsoft website.` - is this microsoft website CORS enabled?

Comment: `$.support.cors = true; // enable cross-domain query` — That isn't what that does. That just fritzes with jQuery's browser detection code so that if the **browser** doesn't support CORS then it makes jQuery think that it does and breaks it. Leave that variable alone.

Comment: What does the Console in your browser's developer tools say? What does the Net tab say? Can you see the request? Is it formatted as you expect? What about the response?

Comment: Quentin: I can see the request. There are 2 messages in the Network tab. The first one is formatted correctly, it has a status of 302 (Moved Temporarily) and this one has the correct cookies in the response. But right after this one, there's a failed request, with incorrect URL (http://undefined/proxy/https://mysharepoint.sharepoint.com/ <= not even the correct address). Why are there two requests to the "same" website? Why is the first one moved temporarily? I updated the question with screenshots of these.

Answer (score 0):

> Can somebody highlight the differences in these two posts?

the main difference between the two "POST"s is, the javascript one is done in a browser that has cross origin limitations, the php "POST" is done on a server that has no such limitations.

> And can somebody build a javascript post just like the php one?

if the destination server is CORS enabled, then what you have looks OK

if the destination server is not CORS enabled, then no, not directly

Comment: edited the original question. the server shouldn't have limitations like that.

Comment: which server are you talking about?

Comment: the sharepoint online server. The URL that I'm trying to access: any sharepoint online instance, with "/_forms/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0" at the end. Please check the question: you can see that I get a response back, but then the request is duplicated and the ajax call always ends up in the "error" section...

Comment: Oh, I see, your javascript isn't accessing ...sharepoint.com directly - it's accessing it via a proxy at 192.168.0.100:3000 and it's that screwing things up, nothing to do with sharepoint

Comment: Yes. But the thing I just updated my question with, is really bugging me. I don't understand why are there two requests, and why the first one has the necessary info, but still fails.